# Bit manipulation (clear n bits)

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Going through the book "Cracking the coding interview" by Gayle Laakmann McDowell, in bit manipulation chapter, it posts a question:

Find the value of (assuming numbers are represented by 4 bits):

```
1011 & (~0 << 2)
```

Now, ~0 = 1 and shifting it two times towards the left yields 100 ( = 0100 to complete the 4 bits). Anding 1011 with 0100 equals 0000.

However, the answer i have is 1000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~0` is not 1 but `1111` (or `0xf`). The `~` operator is a **bitwise** NOT operator, and not a **logical** one (which would be `!`).

So, when shifted by 2 places to the left, the last four bits are `1100`. And `1100 & 1011` is exaclty `1000`.

Comment: "*assuming numbers are represented by 4 bits*" --> `~0` = `0xF`.

Comment: @icepack Deletion of 7 `f`s done. Lesson learned: bit != octet.

Comment: So if the question was put as 1011 & (~0000 << 2), it would have been clearer to me. So in problems like these, first we should always write all numbers involved with the specified number of bits and then perform the operations given following operator precedence. Is this method correct?

Comment: @user85030 Yes. Just like `07:56` and `7:56` denote the same time.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted your answer. Combining this with Matt's response "The 0 will default to being an integer, and the NOT operation will reverse ALL the bits, not just the first." answers my question completely.

Answer (score 2):

`~0` does not equal 1. The `0` will default to being an integer, and the NOT operation will reverse ALL the bits, not just the first.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is the Bitwise Complement Operator.

The value of `~0` should be `1111` in 4 bits .

```
1011 & (~0 << 2)
= 1011 & ( 1111 << 2)
= 1011 &  1100
= 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1011 & (~0 << 2)
```

1. `~0` is not 1 but rather `1111`<sub>2</sub> or `0xF`<sub>16</sub>.
2. Shifting `1111` to the left twice gives `1100` (the two leftmost bits have been dropped and filled in with 0s from the right).
3. Adding `1011 & 1100` gives 1 in each bit position for which the corresponding bit position is 1, otherwise 0. This follows that the result is `1000`.